# Добавление столбца в  MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Я пишу чат с помощю php, mysql, ajax и jQuery. Хочу добавить столбик в mysql-е для добавления даты каждого сообщения, чтобы потом с помощю ajax вывести на экран новые сообщения. Имя моей таблицы в mysql-е messages, в нем есть 3 столбика id, message и date.

```
$message = $_POST['messages'];
    $timestamp=123456789;
    $format="d.m.Y G:i:s";
    $DB->Query("INSERT INTO messages(message, date) VALUES('$message', 'date($format, $timestamp)' )");
```

Так я добавляю message и date в таблицу, но что-то не так, оно добавляет
0000-00-00 00:00:00 в столбике date, помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не пробовали просто `NOW()` вместо `date($format, $timestamp)`?

**Добавлено.**

Так делаете?

```
$DB->Query("INSERT INTO messages(message, date) VALUES ('$message', NOW())");
```

P.S в бд нельзя ввести дату в своем формате. Она всегда там записана как YYYY-MM-DD, вы можете вывести из нее только в своем формате, а дата там храниться только так.

Comment: нет изменений:)

Comment: так делаете?

    $DB->Query("INSERT INTO messages(message, date) VALUES ('$message', NOW())");

P.S в бд нельзя ввести дату в своем формате. Она всегда там записана как YYYY-MM-DD, вы можете вывести из нее только в своем формате, а дата там храниться только так.

Comment: спасибо большое так уже работает:)))) а может вы знаете как с помощю 
ajax выбрать из базы данных последные дабавленные?

Comment: SELECT message FROM messages ORDER BY date LIMIT 0,10

А в качестве клиентской части предлагаю использовать jQuery:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: тоесть у меня код будет типа так?
function timedMsg()
     {
    $.post('ajaxPostServer.php',$('#userArea').serialize(), function(data)
      {
       $("#messages").append('<div>'+data+'</div>');
      });
     setTimeout("timedMsg()", 1000);
    }

ajaxPostServer.php
<?php
 include 'config.php';
 $message = $_POST['messages'];
 $DB->Query("SELECT message FROM messages ORDER BY date LIMIT 0,10");
 echo $message;
?>

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант можно настроить столбец в базе примерно так:

```
`date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Тогда можно вообще не думать вообще об этом столбце и делать вставку примерно так:

```
$DB->Query("INSERT INTO messages(message) VALUES('$message')");
```

Comment: спасибо так тоже работает :)))

Comment: Пожалуйста, не забывайте закрывать вопросы.

Answer (score 0):

У вас неправильный формат даты.

Для mysql правильным форматом даты является:

```
$format="Y-m-d H:i:s";
```

Попробуйте так: (Изменил)

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$DB->Query("INSERT INTO messages(message, date) VALUES('$message', '$date' )");
```

Comment: а юто ничего не меняет:)

Comment: $DB->Query("INSERT INTO messages(message, date) VALUES('$message', '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' )");
так не работает еррор дает в ютом строку